# jQuery custom code dont work with Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Hello I am trying to make a custom slider, which works with the jQuery which I have already tested and made a fiddle as well but I am facing a problem that when I use the same code on Wordpress in my plugin it doesn't work, I dont want to update the jQuery of the Wordpress which originally generated all I need to rewrite some my this code to make it work. I makes problems with `$` and `fn` in console log.

Here is the Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/fqwzdsxh/

my HTML

```
<div id="slider" class="slider_container">
    <center>
        <button type="button" class="previous"> Previous &lt; </button>
        <button type="button" class="next"> Next &gt; </button>
        <img class="slider_image" src="http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/img/grey.gif">
        <img class="slider_image" src="http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/img/grey.gif">
        <img class="slider_image" src="http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/img/grey.gif">
        <img class="slider_image" src="http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/img/grey.gif">
        <img class="slider_image" src="http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/img/grey.gif">
    </center>
</div>
```

my JS

```
$(function(){

    //Lazyload function
    $.fn.lazyload = function(){
        var image = $(this);
        if (image.attr('real-src')){
            image.attr('src', image.attr('real-src'));
            image.removeAttr('real-src');
        }
        return this;
    };

    //Slider constructor
    $.fn.imageSlider = function(){
        this.each(function(){
            var $slider = $(this);

            var $active = $slider.find('img:first');
            $active.addClass('active');
            $active.lazyload();

            //Slider control buttons
            var $nextButton = $slider.find('.next');
            var $prevButton = $slider.find('.previous');

            $prevButton.toggle();

            //Handle if next button should appear
            $nextButton.click(function(){
                var $next = $active.next();
                $active.removeClass('active');
                $next.addClass('active');
                $active = $next;
                $active.lazyload();

                if ($active.next().length == 0){
                    $nextButton.toggle();
                }
                $prevButton.show();

            })

            //Handle if next button should appear
            $prevButton.click(function(){
                var $prev = $active.prev();
                $active.removeClass('active');
                $prev.addClass('active');
                $active = $prev;
                $active.lazyload();

                if ($active.prev().length == 0){
                    $prevButton.toggle();
                }
                $nextButton.show();
            })
        })

            return this;
        };

})

$(document).ready(function(){
    var $slider = $('#slider');
    if ($slider.find('.active').length == 0){
        $slider.imageSlider();
    }
})
```

my css

```
.slider_container {
    position: relative;
}

.slider_container img {
    display:none;
}

.slider_container img.active {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contributions on StackOverflow and I'm glad you got an answer that helped. For future reference and to make sure you always get the best help here, you should try to explain exactly what problem you are having with details of error messages, wrong behaviour etc. It makes it easier for people to help when they know what they are helping with :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

/*
Plugin name: Testing
plugin URI: https://www.google.com
*/

add_action("admin_menu","ders_iki");

function ders_iki()
{
    add_menu_page("Ders iki - Title","ders-iki-menu","manage_options","ders-iki","eklenti_icerigi","dashicons-wordpress-alt");

}

function eklenti_icerigi() 
 {?>
    <form method="POST">
    <div id="slider" class="slider_container">
        <button type="button" class="previous"> Previous &lt; </button>
        <button type="button" class="next"> Next &gt; </button>
</div>
    </form>

<?php
 }

 function Slider_JS() {   
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_slider_script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/slider.js' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init','Slider_JS');


?>
```

**Detailed explanation why to `wp_enqueue_scripts` scripts**

**Reason JS not loading:** add_action allows during page loads / specific events. The function attached it as work like a call back and asks your WordPress to add jQuery script in head element so that it can be accessible from anywhere on your website.

**Another way:** You can also just add jQuery script CDN which can be found on w3 schools page Just add before the `<?php` plugin main page and this way you do not have wp_enqueue_scripts scripts and even `'$'` will work. The reason we have to change all `$` signs was that the Wordpress will treat at `$` as `jQuery` word.

**JS File**

```
jQuery(function () {

    //Lazyload function
    jQuery.fn.lazyload = function () {
        var image = jQuery(this);
        if (image.attr('real-src')) {
            image.attr('src', image.attr('real-src'));
            image.removeAttr('real-src');
        }
        return this;
    };

    //Slider constructor
    jQuery.fn.imageSlider = function () {
        this.each(function () {
            var $slider = jQuery(this);

            var $active = $slider.find('img:first');
            $active.addClass('active');
            $active.lazyload();

            //Slider control buttons
            var $nextButton = $slider.find('.next');
            var $prevButton = $slider.find('.previous');

            // $prevButton.toggle();

            //Handle if next button should appear
            $nextButton.click(function () {

                console.log('dsd')
                var $next = $active.next();
                $active.removeClass('active');
                $next.addClass('active');
                $active = $next;
                $active.lazyload();

                if ($active.next().length == 0) {
                    $nextButton.toggle();
                }
                $prevButton.show();

            })

            //Handle if next button should appear
            $prevButton.click(function () {
                var $prev = $active.prev();
                $active.removeClass('active');
                $prev.addClass('active');
                $active = $prev;
                $active.lazyload();

                if ($active.prev().length == 0) {
                    $prevButton.toggle();
                }
                $nextButton.show();
            })
        })

        return this;
    };

})

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var $slider = jQuery('#slider');
    if ($slider.find('.active').length == 0) {
        $slider.imageSlider();
    }
})
```

Comment: Your jQuery is not loading properly. I have updated my answer try now. You still need to enqueue JS. regardless of your use $ or jQuery. I have tested out on a test plugin its working fine.

Comment: @UsmanMunir, thank you for your answer, but can you update it to explain **why** this fixes the issue please? StackOverflow is a repository of questions & answers for all users, so an explanation would make your answer helpful for users other than the person who asked.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Done.

Comment: Thanks, that will be helpful for other users, and doing this in future questions might also give your answer a better chance of being accepted or upvoted :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten Thanks heaps. Will try to put as much as explanation from now regarding a question answered from now on :)

Comment: No need to overdo it, just as long as it is clear how your answer fixes the problem - code without explanation doesn't usually do that so is discouraged & can get flagged. If you're interested, you should take a look at [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy answering!

Answer (score 1):

It is likely because wordpress' jquery is in [compatibility mode](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/). You may need to replace all `$` references with the more explicit `jQuery` instead.

Comment: can you help me with that

Comment: Basically just find+replace anywhere you use `$` to reference jQuery itself... ie: replace `$.` with `jQuery.` or `$()` with `jQuery()`. You can try this: https://pastebin.com/s4ZZpQzj